# Convert SQL Query to Table Using Pivot Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, pivot-table

Can I know how can I modify the SQL Query below so that the result will turn into expected result using pivot table where () in For MonthYear = Start Date and End Date selected by user ?

SQL Query : [SQL Query Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jqzWY.png) (Image)

Expected Result : [Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NnYp7.png) (Image)

```
                   SELECT * FROM

(

SELECT WR.Work_Type,
                    LEFT(DATENAME(MONTH,WR.Request_Date),3)+' '+STR(YEAR(WR.Request_Date),4) AS MonthYear,
                    CONVERT(INT,STR(YEAR(WR.Request_Date),4)+REPLACE(STR(MONTH(WR.Request_Date),2),' ','0') ) AS MonthYearOrder,
                    COUNT(ISNULL(WR.Request_ID,0)) AS Total 
                    FROM tblWork_Request WR
                     INNER JOIN vWorkTypeByPropertyLevel WT ON WR.CoID=WT.CoID AND WR.Work_Type=WT.Work_Type AND WT.IsWorkRequest=1 
                     LEFT JOIN [UBERIQ_1.5_Property].[dbo].[tblProperty] P ON WR.Property_ID=P.Property_ID                          
                    WHERE WR.CoID='59' and WR.Property_ID='MCST001' 
                    GROUP BY WR.Work_Type,LEFT(DATENAME(MONTH,WR.Request_Date),3)+' '+STR(YEAR(WR.Request_Date),4),
                    CONVERT(INT,STR(YEAR(WR.Request_Date),4)+REPLACE(STR(MONTH(WR.Request_Date),2),' ','0') ) 

) t
pivot (
SUM(Total)
FOR MonthYear IN ()

) as pivot_table
```

Result :-

```
Work_Type          | MonthYear | MonthYearOrder | Total
----------------------------------------------------------
A.1 Problem Code 1 | Jun 2020  | 202006         | 3
AHU faulty         | Nov 2020  | 202011         | 6
AirCondition       | May 2020  | 202005         | 1
Exterior           | Jun 2020  | 202006         | 2
```

Expected Result :-

```
Work Type           | Jan 2020 | Feb 2020 | Mar 2020 | Apr 2020 | May 2020 | Jun 2020 | Jun 2020 | Jul 2020 | Aug 2020 | Sep 2020 | Oct 2020 | Nov 2020 | Dec 2020 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
A.1 Problem Code 1  | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 3        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        |  
AHU Faulty          | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 6        | 0    |
AirCondition        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 1        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0   |
Exterior            | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 2        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0   |
```

Please advise. Thank you.

Comment: Please don't use images, post your query sample data and expected results as formatted text so we can all read it and copy and paste if desired.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
--Variables for dynamic columns and query
DECLARE @columns NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''
DECLARE @ifnullcolumns     NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''
DECLARE @query     NVARCHAR(MAX)

;WITH months(YearMonth) AS
(
    SELECT 202001
    UNION ALL
    SELECT YearMonth + 1
    FROM months
    WHERE YearMonth < 202012
)

SELECT 
     @columns += QUOTENAME(YearMonth) + ',',
     @ifnullcolumns += 'ISNULL(' + QUOTENAME(YearMonth) + ', 0) AS ' + QUOTENAME(YearMonth)+','
FROM 
    months

-- remove last , from the column list
SET @columns = LEFT(@columns, LEN(@columns) - 1)
SET @ifnullcolumns = LEFT(@ifnullcolumns, LEN(@ifnullcolumns) - 1)

-- Building dynamic query with pivot
SET @query ='
SELECT Work_Type, '+ @ifnullcolumns +' FROM (
    select Work_Type, MonthYerOrder, Total
    from Sample) t
PIVOT(
    SUM(Total)
    FOR MonthYerOrder IN ('+ @columns +')
) AS pivot_table;'

EXECUTE sp_executesql @query
```

Result of this query: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/96333/63

Comment: Can I know how can I convert the query to a string query (SQL = "") to be used in asp.net page. I am still relatively new to SQL so I am not sure on how to achieve that.

Comment: you can create store procedure and call it in your code with the required parameter like  start and end range for month/year that have been hard coded in the query i.e. 202001, 202012